# Transform hog descriptor from Matlab to Java OpenCV

Tags: android, matlab, opencv, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

I have some codes which written in Matlab and I want to convert them into Java OpenCV to be suitable for Android devices. In Matlab code I use `extractHOGFeatures` which is a function in the computer vision toolbox to extract the hog vector. While I use HOGDescriptor class in OpenCV to extract the hog vector.

However, the output vectors from both are different from each other. I try to understand the problem and what I found are:

the block size, the cell size, the block overlap and the number of bins are the same in both vectors that obtained from `extractHOGFeatures (Matlab)` and HOGDescriptor class(OpenCV). But the size of sliding window in OpenCV is 64*128. While in Matlab I can not determine what is the default size of the sliding window even when I access the documentary of the function.

Can anybody help me how I can obtain the same output?

I need OpenCV modification not Matlab since in my project situation I can not change the Matlab code

Comment: `extractHOGFeatures` computes a HoG descriptor for the whole image. It does not have a notion of a sliding window.